# How to use "double for loop in python" to get the data (Values) not repeated(duplicated) as a last loop values

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

**Would you check this codes as python
output (expected) : ['A' : [10,11,12,13], 'B' : [1,2,3,4]]
But, "B" values repeated  ['A': [1,2,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3,4]]**

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Lotno_list = ['A','B']

count_merge = []
total_count = []
total_dict = {}

for Lotno in Lotno_list:
  folder_list = os.listdir(r'../{}/'.format(lotno)) # get the folder_list in the folder (Lotno) 
  count_merge.clear()
  for element in folder_list: # ex) folder_list = ['A01','A02','A03','A04'] when Lotno = 'A'into for
    element_list = os.listdir(r'../{}/{}/'.format(lotno,element)) 
    element_count = len(element_list)
    # Count files in the folder ex) A01 ... 
    count_merge.append(element_count) 
  total_dict[Lotno] = count_merge
print(total_dict)
```

Comment: `Lotno_list = [A,B]` Should they be strings? Ex: `Lotno_list = ['A','B']`. (Side note:, the terminology is "nested for loop" and not "double for loop")

Comment: Thank u for your help you right, i skipped str format in my question. but still it remain 'B' values repeated.